# How to get sub array using JsonUtility in unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

This is the JSON I have:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"layoutLabel":"Sameer Non Custom","orbNumber":"["0","1","2","3"]"},
{"id":2,"layoutLabel":"Samer Custom","orbNumber":"["2","3","4","5"]"}],"status":200}
```

Here are my C# classes in unity to Deserialise it:

```
[System.Serializable]
class GetLayoutsResult
{
    public List<LayoutData> data;
    public int status;
}

[System.Serializable]
class LayoutData
{
    public int id;
    public string layoutLabel;
    public string [] orbNumber;
}
```

Here is the code to deserialise it:

```
     GetLayoutsResult P = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetLayoutsResult>(w.text);
        if (P.status == 200)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < P.data.Count; i++)
            {
               Debug.Log(layoutEditButtonScript.layoutName + " " + P.data[i].positionX[0])
            }
 }
```

I don't get positionX array in this. I get an index array error instead. Can anyone help me deserialise a sub array in unity ?

Comment: Would be simple and straightforward using `Newtonsoft Json.Net - JsonConvert`

Comment: Unitys built in Json utility is actually faster and just as simple to use as newtonsoft. Benchmarks for speed here: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3303

Comment: @turnipinrut Thanks for the details, I need to verify through use cases, since `Newtonsoft Json.Net` is arguably the most popular `Json serializer` used by the community, also here does this serializer needs `[Serialize]` attribute (I hope not), because that would make it difficult for lot of inbuilt classes in .Net framework, which are not marked by attribute by default, also some places where we don't mark deliberately, as a custom serializer need to be invoked at run-time ( like Protobuf) for binary serialization

Comment: @MrinalKamboj In a Unity application, popularity of a library is not the factor that matters at all. Its always better to use a library which comes with the tool. So recommendation is `JsonUtility`.

Comment: @UmairM, this means, there's a default Json serializer that is bundled with .net framework (JavaScriptSerializer), everyone shall use it, not the other custom libraries. 
Quite strange logic that popularity of the library doesn't matter. In fact its exactly opposite, that's why so many custom frameworks are used based on popularity and community recommendation.
If you cannot use in Unity, that's quite different, otherwise, its always good to choose the best for the given use case.

Comment: I completely understood that fact but I was talking specifically about Unity which uses `.NET 2.0` and I believe that `JavaScriptSerializer` was introduced in later versions of .NET. Having said that `JsonUtility` is default for Unity applications, even if there are other tools which are far more popular.

Comment: Alright @UmairM, thanks for the good information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your json is incorrectly formatted.

This:

```
"orbNumber": "["0", "1", "2", "3"]"
```

Should be this:

```
"orbNumber": ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

No need to put quotes around an array.

Also, you need to rename positionX to orbNumber in your model class.